# How to share multiple "tagged" functions (symbols) like f[a][b] in parallel kernels?

Tags: parallelization

I would like to give some context: I need to analyse many data sets stored in files using different kind of analyses. To keep track I like to tag each results of my analysis for example like `result["analysis1"]["file1"]`. For this I am used to write code like this:

```
analyse[params_][file_]:=Module[{data},
  data=accessdata[file];
  result["analysis1"][file]=doanalysis1[params, data];
  result["analysis2"][file]=doanalysis2[params, data];
]

(*analalyse many files*)
files={"file1", "file2", ...};
Map[analyse[params],files];

(* aggregate results e.g. in plots or histograms*)
ListPlot[result["analysis1"]/@files];
Histogram[result["analysis2"]/@files]
```

This works fine and gives me great flexibility. For example if I need to re-analise e.g. "file17", maybe with some other parameters, I can just call `analyse[otherparam]["file17"]` and plot the updated results again. or I can save the results with `Save["resultfile", result]`.

My problem arises, if I try to parallelize this.

```
ParallelMap[analyse[params],files];
```

does not work, because each kernel will have its own version of `result`.
I tried:

```
SetSharedFunction[result];
ParallelMap[analyse[params],files];
```

But I got error messages from all kernels like:

```
Set::write: Tag Null in Null["file1"] is protected.
```

Also I tried:

```
SetSharedFunction[result["analysis1"]]
```

which apparently does not even get executed.
How can one share `result` such that the code above works with `ParallelMap`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that avoids the use of tagged functions inside the `ParallelMap`but allows its use outside.

```
analyse[params_][file_]:=Module[{data},
  data=accessdata[file];
  result["analysis1", file]=doanalysis1[params, data];
  result["analysis2", file]=doanalysis2[params, data];
]
result[tag_][file_]:= result[tag, file]
SetSharedFunction[result];
ParallelMap[analyse[params],files];
ListPlot[result["analysis1"]/@files];
```

Still I would be interested in other ideas!